# Magento2 error when making reference for a module controller

Tags: magento2, extend, admin-controller

I think I am misunderstanding the concepts of reference when it comes to controllers.

Reference class

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render;

class Render extends Render
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $component = $this->factory->create($this->_request->getParam('namespace'));
        $this->prepareComponent($component);
        if($this->_request->getParam('namespace')=='product_listing'){
            $this->_response->appendBody((string) $this->customFunction($component->render()));
        }
        else{
            $this->_response->appendBody((string) $component->render());
        }

        return parent::execute();
    }

    protected function customFunction($items){
        //code here...
    }
}
```

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render" />
</config>
```

I receive a error:

```
 Initialization error component, check the spelling of the name or the correctness of the call.
```

What is wrong here ? What am I missing ?

**EDIT :**

I also found this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3177 .
They say it was a problem with the nginx configuration, but I am using apache 2.4 ...

```
Magento Version 2.0.2 CE
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, the reason why it did not work was because I invoked

```
return parent::execute();
```

Once I removed that, everything started working just fine... I have absolutely no idea why... maybe I had some old info or something..

Answer (score 1):

This line should throw an error:

```
class Render extends Render
```

you cannot use an alias the same as the class name you are creating.

Instead try this

```
use Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render as CoreRender;

class Render extends CoreRender
```

Comment: no change... i flushed the cache and removed the cache, page_cache and generation directories as well, run setup:upgrade - no change

Comment: I used a different alias before that, but the result was the same...

Comment: I will vote up your answer, because you make a very good point anyway

Comment: I made an update, if it can help ... ? I will continue looking

Comment: sorry. I have no idea. I will post more if I find more.

Comment: don't bother it is all good now :) thank you for your help